# cycle through array using index

Tags: ruby, indexing, cycle

I have an array

`arr = [1,2,3,4,5]`

and I'm wondering if there is a way to cycle through it so something like:

```
i = 2
arr[3+n]
```

would return `1`, rather than `nil`

Is that possible using the index, or even with `next`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perform a [modulo](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Numeric.html#method-i-25) on the index using the array size:

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
arr[5 % arr.size]  #=> 1
```

Comment: I think this is more in line with what the OP is looking for; To me it looks like the question is dealing with an index that's running off the end of the array, and using the mod operator will fix that.

Comment: This is what I ended up using. Worked perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

It's called [cycle](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-cycle):

```
c = [1,2,3,4,5].cycle
10.times{p c.next}
```

Comment: +1 Nice. Since `cycle` is just returning an Enumerator, you can do some interesting things with [`lazy`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-lazy): `(1..5).cycle.lazy.first(10)`.

Comment: This is great. But why does this return 10, instead of 5?

Comment: Another alternative is `rotate`

Comment: @mr.musicman [`times`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Integer.html#method-i-times) returns the object it was called on.

Comment: `(1..5).cycle.lazy.first(10)` is equivalent to `[*(1..5)] * 2 # => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` for this purpose.

Comment: @theTinMan Right, but it’s not nearly as fun! `;)`